Problem in importing library Chaquopy in Android Studio,
I need your help, i have no idea what have i done.
All of Documentation of Chaquopy are different. I need your help  i just want to run my .py file on Android.
I don't know how to call my file.
I already add maven url
build.gradle.kts (:app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    id("com.chaquo.python") version "15.0.1" apply false
}

android {
    namespace = "com.kanjengdev.biomey"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.kanjengdev.biomey"
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "2.4 (Beta)"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.activity)
    implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.navigation.fragment)
    implementation(libs.navigation.ui)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.ext.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)

    // Python
    implementation(libs.chaquopy)
}

build.gradle.kts (App)
And i already add the chaquopy library
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.android.library) apply false
//    alias(libs.plugins.chaquopy) apply false
    id("com.chaquo.python") version "15.0.1" apply false
}

settings.gradle.kts
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google {
            content {
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.android.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("com\\.google.*")
                includeGroupByRegex("androidx.*")
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
        }
        maven {
            url = uri("https://chaquo.com/maven")
        }

    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url = uri("https://jitpack.io")
        }
        maven {
            url = uri("https://chaquo.com/maven")
        }

    }
}

rootProject.name = "Biomey"
include(":app")
 



All of Documentation of Chaquopy are different

That's why you should follow the documentation of the version you want to use, and not mix things up between different versions. Going by the documentation for the current version, 15.0.1, there are several problems with your configuration:

When you declare the plugin in the build.gradle.kts (:app) file, you shouldn't use the version or apply settings. It should just look like this:
id("com.chaquo.python")


The maven { url = uri("https://chaquo.com/maven") } sections are unnecessary.

The implementation(libs.chaquopy) line is unnecessary.


